# A summary statistic for an unknown distribution

Tags: descriptive-statistics

A trial consists of the following: a number is chosen uniformly from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ then put through a function $f$ yielding a value in $\{W, L\}$. (Think successes, failures of the numbers.)

Do this $N$ times. Let $W_i$ be the count of $i$ mapping to $W$ (say, $wins$) and similarly $L_i$ ($losses$) so that $\displaystyle\sum^n W_i + \sum^n L_i = N.$

If we don't know anything about $f$, is there a statistic that might still summarize the data? I want to pick the best of $W_i$, whatever that might mean: $max(W_i, L_i)$ or $max(\frac{W_i}{W_i + L_i}, \frac{L_i}{W_i + L_i})$ first come to mind. Are either one of these "better" in some sense than the other? I can think of one: the second safeguards against the unlikey scenario when a number $i$ is chosen way more often than the others.

I suppose the real value I would get out of an answer is a heads up to where I can read more about this kind of stuff on my own. (What kind of statistics would you call this?)

Comment: Do you want to construct a probability distribution, is that what you're after? For binary data (win/loss) you'd end up with some sort of binomial distribution

Comment: Also, does each trial produce _two numbers_ i.e. a pair $(W_i, L_i)$?

Comment: Finally, do we know anything about the values that $W_i$ and $L_i$ can take? It appears that both should be non-negative, but are they?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos $W_1 + W_2 + \ldots + W_n$ (wins for $1, 2, \ldots, n$). Same for $L_i$. Each trial produces a $W$ or $L$. At the end of $N$ trials, we count up the $W$'s for $1$, the $L$'s for $1$, the $W$'s for $2$, the $L$'s for $2$, ... Re your last question: no, I suppose you could say they're just used to count the Wins or Losses for $1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: @Lennart. Sorry, it's hard for me to say much more than I have already :(

Comment: Anyone: feel free to completely change my terminology and notation above to conform to a well-known, perhaps more understandable ones.

Comment: Could you tell us where the motivation for this comes from? Since $f$ is a *function*, after you have sampled all of 1,2,...,n at least once, *you know f*.